# QLPreviewController only shows a single file

Tags: objective-c, ios, events, qlpreviewcontroller

I am using a QLPreviewController to display a set of files. However, it only shows the first one and I can't seem to swipe or do anything to show the second. What am I doing wrong? Do I have to set it manually? If so - how would I go about doing that?

This is from my AppDelegate.m:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // normal viewcontroller init here 

    [self showPreview] ;

    return YES;
}

NSArray* documents ;
QLPreviewController* preview ;

- (void) showPreview
{
    documents = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"photo" , @"photo2" , nil ] ;

    preview = [[QLPreviewController alloc] init];
    preview.dataSource = self;
    preview.delegate = self;

    preview.view.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    //save a reference to the preview controller in an ivar
    //  self.previewController = preview;
    //refresh the preview controller
    [preview reloadData];
    [[preview view] setNeedsLayout];
    [[preview view] setNeedsDisplay];
    [preview refreshCurrentPreviewItem];
    preview.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    //add it  
    [self.viewController.view addSubview:preview.view];
}
```

I also declared the two callback functions in the same AppDelegate.m file:

```
- (id <QLPreviewItem>) previewController: (QLPreviewController *) controller previewItemAtIndex: (NSInteger) index
{
    NSString* filename = [documents objectAtIndex:index] ;      //  @"photo" ; 
    NSURL* returnURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: filename ofType:@"jpg" ]] ;

    return returnURL ;
}

- (NSInteger) numberOfPreviewItemsInPreviewController: (QLPreviewController *) controller
{
    return [documents count];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are displaying it wrong.
QLPreviewController is a UIViewController, which means you basically have 2 ways of displaying it:

1. Push it into your UINavigationController.
2. Display it modally (this can be done with or without a UINavigationController - depends if you want a navigation bar).

If you choose option 2 you get "free" navigation arrows to switch between items. 
For option 1 you need to create the arrows yourself.

This following is taken from the [QLPreviewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/QLPreviewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) documentation:

> If there is more than one item in the list, a modally-presented (that
>   is, full-screen) controller displays navigation arrows to let the user
>   switch among the items. For a Quick Look preview controller pushed
>   using a navigation controller, you can provide buttons in the
>   navigation bar for moving through the navigation list.